# Error while Trying to load Powershell Module "MSOnline" in ASP.NET web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, module, office365-apps

Good morning I have one problem trying o load a Powershell Module called MSOnline in a ASP.NET 
After following this links:

http://www.msdigest.net/2012/03/how-to-connect-to-office-365-with-powershell/

http://blogs.technet.com/b/educloud/archive/2013/01/23/managing-office-365-for-education-using-powershell.aspx

This is a Button that run a script via Code Behind in C#. When I was trying to load the module it threw an exception.

```
 protected void Bexecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //            Import-Module MSOnline
        try
        {
            //Loading MSOnline using a InitialSessionState
            InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
            iss.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "MSOnline" });
            //Before the solution iss has an exception of "not found" the MSOnline Module

            //Create a runspace
            Runspace test = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);

            //Open a Runspace
            test.Open();
            //Create a Pipeline 
            Pipeline pipeLine = test.CreatePipeline();

            //Create the StringBuilder to get append the script
            StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();

            //Take the script from Tscript (TextBoxt with ID="Tscript" in default.aspx
            script.AppendLine(@"Get-Module -ListAvailable");
            //Add the script and commands to the pipeline;

            pipeLine.Commands.AddScript(script.ToString());

            //Execute script and get the PSObject Results collection
            Collection<PSObject> resultObjects = pipeLine.Invoke();

            //Close the Runspace
            test.Close();

            if (resultObjects.Count > 0)
            {
            /*** DO SOMETHING WITH THE PSObjects ***/
            }
        }
        catch (System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException ex)
        {
            status.AppendLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

What I need is what could be wrong. I referenced the system.management.automation (dll). But I don't have a clue why is not listed if it's installed it. Thank you for the help.

I have found MSOnline .dll files in : C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MSOnline
But If I tried to add manually from visual studio it says "that MSOnline doesn't exist".
This is quite weird, because all have same permissions to folder. What's going on! :S This is so frustrating...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get ASP.NET web app run under x64 bit architecture you should do this:

1, MS Online Services Assistant needs to be downloaded and installed
Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant – 64 bit version  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=236300

2.MS Online Module for PowerShell needs to be  downloaded and installed
Microsoft Online Services Module for Windows PowerShell (64-bit version) http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=236297

After this step you can run: get-module -ListAvailable and the Module MSOnline will be listed.
But it is still not working on 64 bits SOs. the original poster used win8 64bits and I am using win 8.1 64 bits and it works as well.

3. Copy the MSOnline module folder from (Path1) to (Path2) where

   (Path1) -> "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MSOnline"

   and

   (Path2) -> "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MSOnline"

Considering I'm running this on VS2013 under Windows 8.1 and 64 bits arquitecture.

After doing this the MSOnline Module is listed in the Get-Module -ListAvailable (from webapp, not just for powershell)), so I could import it and use it.